# Anyone in the enterprise using Google-hosted jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, cdn, google-api

I would like to use Google's copy of jQuery, to spare some load on my company's local web servers:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

While this is great for many sites (include stackoverflow and my personal website), I am hesitant to introduce this change to my company's public website.

Personally, I trust Google in this regard, but it would be easier to convince management if some other major companies had taken the leap already.

Anyone know of major enterprise companies who use google-hosted jQuery (or other JS libraries)? Something in the league of Oracle, IBM, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chances of someone being able to see your website and not google's is very, **very** slim.  We use it daily, no problems.  The only really high traffic site pulling from the Google CDN directly I know of is  [Twitter](http://twitter.com/).

For e-commerce sites like you're talking about, it's not that they don't trust google, but at a certain point you have your own CDN for the rest of your site...much easier from a management standpoint to use it for everything.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Twitter - this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I don't entirely see why such a decision should be impacted by whether or not huge enterprises such as IBM use Google's CDN. What you should do, is explain the [performance and bandwidth-saving potential](http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) of doing so, and at the same time present them with a plan B:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write('<script src="', 'js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js', '" type="text/JavaScript"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```

(the above code was taken from [this page)](http://snipplr.com/view/28239/google-cdn-hosted-jquery-with-local-fallback/)